# Files are not deleting through a samba share

Tags: kubuntu, samba

I'm running Kubuntu 21.04. I have an external USB3 8TB drive formatted as `ext4`. It is being shared on the network as SAMBA share. The name of the drive is `nest`, and my `smb.conf` is configured as below:

```
[nest]
comment = nest
path = /media/JMS10/nest
read only = no
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
public = yes
force user = JMS10
```

I am connecting to the share from an Windows 10 laptop. When Windows asks for a username/password, I'm using `JMS10` as the username, and I specify the password. I'm able to browse and view all of the contents. The problem is when I delete a file, it tells me it is deleted, but when I refresh the folder the files are still there. Also when I open the folder physically from my Kubuntu PC I can also see the files.

So I'm not sure why the files aren't getting deleted. It used to work fine before, and at some point it stopped working properly. I haven't changed the `smb.conf` in a long time.

Comment: hi JMS. if you do "ls -la on /media/JMS10/nest", what permissions are you seing?

Comment: try this... change force user to root and use explicit write list = {users} separated by space. Remember restarting you samba server.

Comment: The user and group is JMS10. And the permissions are `drwxrwxr-x` for directories, and `-rw-rw-r--` for files.

Comment: I tried `force user = root`, and `write list = JMS10` but it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: perms look ok. is it one file or every file?

Comment: It is every file. I also have another drive and it does the same thing. I rebooted the machine also.

Comment: still diging... :-) it is strange because you said that have not change anything. what's the output of groups command for JMS10 account?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128988/discussion-between-jms10-and-jpbrain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the issue. There were a few things wrong with my setup. Also, it was not logging any error messages in the `/var/log/samba` folder. My guess is that since I was connecting from a Windows client, there is probably an edge case (bug) that I hit.

First, I removed the `public` and `guest ok` properties. I found out that they are synonymous, and if you look at my original config above, I was setting `yes` for one and `no` for the other.

Second I added my user to SAMBA by runnning `smbpasswd -a JMS10`, and added the `valid users` line below. After that it started working.

```
[nest]
path = /media/JMS10/nest
read only = no
browsable = yes
valid users = JMS10
```

So my setup was incorrect, and not sure why it was working before without any issues. My assumption was that SAMBA doesn't need a separate username, but that was incorrect. For any newbies out there, SAMBA doesn't integrate with your Linux account. So you have you create a new user for SAMBA, and the password is also different from your Linux account.

Comment: the password is also different from your Linux account. I do not think this is correct and in my case on 6 different machines it is not.

Comment: That's very odd. Maybe because I passed the `-a` parameter it sets a different password.